# Need help calculating time difference between a 4 instance clockout in 24 hour time

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

Alright, there are 4 instances of a clock in/out occuring. There's a clock in, a clock out for lunch, clock in from lunch, and a final clock out. It's a 24 hour clock, and the time needs to be rounded to the nearest .25 (15 minutes) at the very end.

```
   *For reference, a is the first clock in hour, b is the clock out for lunch hour
    c is the clock in hour from lunch, and d is the final clock out hour

   *e is the first clock in minute, f is the clock out for lunch minute
    g is the clock in from lunch minute, and h is the final clock out minute

   *So for example, if somebody clocked in at 5:30, a=5 and f=30
    a clock out for lunch at 12:00 gives b=12 and g=0, etc.

   *The way this code works in a nutshell is to find the total time elapsed and then
    subtract the lunch break time from it. 


   //Find total time
    a=d-a;
    e=h-e;

    //Find lunch break time
    y=c-b;
    z=g-f;

    if(e>=0 && z>=0){
        hours=a-y;
        minutes=e-z;
        if(minutes<0){minutes=minutes*(-1);}
    }else if(e<0 && z<0){
        e=e*(-1);
        z=z*(-1);
        hours=a-y;
        minutes=e-z;
        if(minutes<0){minutes=minutes*(-1);}
    }else{
        if(e<0){e=e*(-1);}
        if(z<0){z=z*(-1);}
        if(e<=z){hours=a-y-1;}
        else{hours=a-y;}
        minutes=e-z;
        if(minutes<0){minutes=minutes*(-1);}
    }

    a=hours;
    e=minutes;

    //This rounds to the nearest 15 minutes/quarter hour        
    if(e<15){
        if(e>=8){e=15;}
        else if(e<8){e=0;}}
    if(e<=30 && e>=15){
        if(e>=23){e=30;}
        else if(e<23){e=15;}}
    if(e<=45 && e>30){
        if(e>=38){e=45;}
        else if(e<38){e=30;}}
    if(e<=60 && e>45){
        if(e>=53){e=0;}
        else if(e<53){e=45;}}

    e=e/60;
    a=a+e;
}

if(a<0){a=a+24;}

$(totaltime).attr('value',a);
```

}

The code is very close to working, there are just random cases where it won't work, and it'll be off by an hour or .5 of an hour or so. Also, this is written in javascript on an HTML page hosted on a highly restricted server, so I can't really add any new libraries or anything.

DEFINITELY feel free to scrap my code if you have a better idea, those three if/else statements are a little confusing to explain, and it's why the code isn't working anyways. I mostly showed the code to show I've been putting some effort into this and am not just trying to take advantage of your help haha.

I also apologize but I have to step away from the computer for a while, so if you have some suggestions or ways to solve this problem toss them out there please and I'll take a look at them when I get back.

Comment: Why are you storing the minutes and hours separately?

Comment: That's just how they get input through a website. Hours in one field, minutes in through another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let javascript do all the work with the date class:

```
//Assuming the day is today
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDay();
//

var clockIn = new Date(year, month, day, a, e).getTime();
var clockOut = new Date(year, month, day, b, f).getTime();
var clockIn_afterLunch = new Date(year, month, day, c, g).getTime();
var clockOut_afterLunch = new Date(year, month, day, d, h).getTime();

var preLunchTimeWorked = clockOut - clockIn;
var postLunchTimeWorked = clockOut_afterLunch - clockIn_afterLunch;

var timeWorked = preLunchTimeWorked + postLunchTimeWorked;

var secondsWorked = timeWorked/1000;
var minutesWorked = secondsWorked/60;
var hoursWorked = minutesWorked/60;
//Much easier to work with in my opinion
```

Hope that helps you get to your answer

Answer (score 0):

The (fairly) standard way to deal with times is to convert everything to seconds, and do the math in seconds.

time1 = seconds1 + (60 * minutes1) + (3600 *hours1)

etc.  If times can span midnight, you'll want to reference them to some epoch time (astronomers use midnight 1 Jan 2000).

Then subtract your times, round to whatever precision you need (15 minutes = 900 seconds), then convert your deltas to hours and minutes.